ShadCN UI combobox only working with keyboard not with mouse
I have a very simple app that consists of only a combobox and a card (it is going to be embedded on a Wordpress). NextJS, ShadCN ui.
The combobox for some reason only works with keyboard, not with the mouse. Even if I copy the examples directly from ShadCN ui website it does not work.
I am sure it is something easy but I cant figure it out.
Here is my code:
'use client'

import { ChevronsUpDown } from 'lucide-react'
import { Batch, batches } from '@/lib/batch'
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import {
  Command,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
  CommandList,
} from '@/components/ui/command'
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/popover'
import { useState } from 'react'
import InfoCard from './info-card'

export function Combobox() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState<Batch | null>(null)

  const filteredBatches = batches.filter((batch) =>
    batch.number.includes(inputValue)
  )

  const handleClick = (batch: Batch) => {
    console.log('clicked')
    setCurrentItem(batch)
    setOpen(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <PopoverTrigger asChild>
          <Button
            variant='outline'
            role='combobox'
            aria-expanded={open}
            className='w-[500px] justify-between'
          >
            {value
              ? batches.find((batch) => batch.number === value)?.number
              : 'Type your batch number...'}
            <ChevronsUpDown className='ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50' />
          </Button>
        </PopoverTrigger>
        <PopoverContent className='w-[500px] p-0'>
          <Command>
            <CommandInput
              placeholder='Search batch number...'
              value={inputValue}
              onValueChange={setInputValue}
            />
            <CommandEmpty>No batch found.</CommandEmpty>
            <CommandList>
              <CommandGroup>
                {filteredBatches.map((batch) => (
                  <CommandItem
                    key={batch.number}
                    value={batch.number}
                    onSelect={() => handleClick(batch)}
                    className='hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-400'
                  >
                    {batch.number} - {batch.fishery}
                  </CommandItem>
                ))}
              </CommandGroup>
            </CommandList>
          </Command>
        </PopoverContent>
      </Popover>

      <InfoCard batch={currentItem} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Combobox

I have it deployed here so you can see that it works with keyboard:
https://aisbatchnumbers.vercel.app/
Code is here:
https://github.com/santivdt/ais-batch-numbers
Hopefully someone knows the solution ..

Your element has the following utility class: data-[disabled]:pointer-events-none. The meaning of this selector is that it takes effect when the data-disabled attribute is present on the element.
And the element has the data-disabled value by default. Although the value is false, the fact that data-disabled exists is still satisfied.
If you want it to take effect when the data-disabled value is true, change your utility class to the following form: data-[disabled=true]:pointer-events-none.

Thank you so much , that works. I am not sure I understand completely why it comes like this out of the box (ShadCN ui). Am I overlooking a feature or a way that this is normally used? I've just deleted the data-[disabled]:pointer-events-none from the component and now it works. Thanks!

@Santi I looked at the code on their official website, and their components do not have data-disabled by default. It's possible that another part of your code added this attribute, but I'm not entirely sure.

Thanks for checking, I ll dive into it but am happy it is solved anyway :)

You have to replace data-disabled to data-[disabled ='true'] from the command.tsx (the command component).
This might be helpful: https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/2944#issuecomment-1985153126

Adding data-[disabled]:pointer-events-auto in the className of CommandItem fixed the problem.
I checked the className in command.tsx file, and it already had data-[disabled=true] instead of data-[disabled] as mentioned in other answers.

This issue still persists.. as I checked data-[disabled=true]:pointer-events-none has been set in the CommandItem and still needs keyboard to select an item. I fix mine by adding className="pointer-events-auto" in the CommandItem.
<CommandItem value={proj.label}
  key={proj.value}
  onSelect={() => {form.setValue("projects", proj.value)}}
  className="pointer-events-auto"> // Add here
  {proj.label}
  <Check className={cn("ml-auto h-4 w-4", proj.value === field.value ? "opacity-100": "opacity-0")}/>
</CommandItem>


Hi! To improve your answer, I would recommend explaining why the class name fixes the problem
